# android-mode can't find project root error

Tags: android

I want to use Emacs for Android development, so I installed [`android-mode`](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode).

But I get an error.  I entering path, package, activity names and I get "can't find project root" error.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to this code in android-mode.el

```
(defmacro android-in-root (body)
  "Execute BODY form with project root directory as
``default-directory''.  The form is not executed when no project
root directory can be found."
  `(let ((android-root-dir (android-root)))
     (if android-root-dir
       (let ((default-directory android-root-dir))
         ,body)
       (error "can't find project root"))))
```

If you remove the (error "can't find project root") it will work in this case. I don't know the implications of this removal for other situations, but it is discussed [here](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode/issues/50) and [here](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode/pull/52).

I was having the same problem. I removed the error and it worked.